# Using Form to Input Google Maps Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have attempted to create an app that will create a map with attributes based on the values of a form.

[HERE](http://googlemap.design.hosting-mate.com/) is the link to the test page. Once you fill in the form with all the necessary information and click "Submit", the `#map` should be filled with the map and all relevant attributes.

**NOTE:** The Map icon on the left of the page is the Map div.

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/f3rep9xh/) is the link to the jsFiddle with all my code.

I have tried a few different things to make it work but nothing seems to work!

Any help or explanation for the cause would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the google maps API key in your actual code?

Comment: I have tried that, however an error just appears in the middle of the screen. The console just states that the function to run the map was not a function?

Comment: That's usually caused my missing brackets or semi colons

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3 and it will detect if any brackets were not closed. It doesn't appear that is the issue.

Could it be possible that the error is caused because the script for the map is being loaded from an external file?

Comment: Not really, Have you assigned the API keys for sure, its not there in both links. I dont expect you to add it in your jsfiddle but its missing on your demo link too.

Comment: I removed it as I was progressively trying to find the fault. I will re-add it for you :)

Comment: Try that now! :)

Comment: The google Maps API is not enabled, go to the google developer console and enable it

Comment: This is the updated JsFiddle, exactly as it is in Sublime

https://jsfiddle.net/f3rep9xh/2/

I have also updated the website again.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to the google developer console and enable the google maps module for your code to work

try put your initmap() function at the outermost part of your javascript.

Comment: I have now enabled the Google Maps Javascript API

Comment: Even with the API enabled it doesn't work. The error still appears?

Comment: There is a syntax error somewhere in the code that you havent provided on jsfiddle

Comment: The updated jsFiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/f3rep9xh/2/

I have also updated the website demo

Comment: Did you copy the code from some source, its all messed up. you dont need an init map callback at all. The order of the code is weird and may many things that are wrong.

Comment: Could you please update the jsFiddle so I can see how it should be done? I have created the source myself based on a source found on the web.

Comment: Is there any way you could inform me of what is done wrong and why the code wont run?

Comment: I did just notice that the ID of my button to activate the code was not set. I have set it and it still did not work :(

Comment: I have also corrected a few more bits of code to activate the function to create the map, however none of the attributes are being set.

The demo website is updated to show the results